# Create Activestorage record for already-existing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have a non-Rails service generating and then uploading files to S3. I want my Rails app to create an Activestorage record for each, so that each `FileResult` `has_one_attached` `file` or similar to refer to within the Rails app.

Do I have any options here that won't necessitate re-uploading?